# Split & Rename pdf file using vba

Tags: vba, pdf

I received a merged file including multiple payslips.
There is a specific number in a particular place on every payslip.
I hoped to use this exact number as each file name (Eg. 37224.pdf)
I tried to split and name into separate payslips using the below VBA code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub pdf()
Dim Acro_app As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim Acro_PDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim Acro_NewPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Set Acro_app = New Acrobat.AcroApp
Set Acro_PDDoc = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Acro_PDDoc.Open "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PDF\Slip.pdf"
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To Acro_PDDoc.GetNumPages() - 1
Set Acro_NewPDDoc = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Acro_NewPDDoc.Create
Acro_NewPDDoc.InsertPages -1, Acro_PDDoc, i, 1, 1

Acro_NewPDDoc.Save 1, "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PDF\S" & i & ".pdf"

Next i
End Sub
```

After running the code the filenames appeared as S1.pdf, S2.pdf … etc.  but I want to do it as 37224.pdf, 36299.pdf … etc

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Each separated page has a number at a specific location.  I expect it to be used as the file name.  Can I edit my code for that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to split a pdf file into pages by using a single console line command , if you have a copy of PDFtools or similar on the machine (even Powshell has PSwritePDF as a download module).

For windows users there is a modern 64 bit 2023 version of pdftotext available from GitHub https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows or for 32bit use there is the updated Xpdf version currently 4.04 http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html HOWEVER that does not have PDFseperate

the power of pdftotext is it can extract a string of text from a window in a PDF page, here I have renamed two S1.pdf and S2.pdf by simply defining an area which for illustration is coloured green, and I defined the window as

`-x 100 -W 300 -y 50 -H 25`

so as to compensate for that horizontal variation, thus if you have slight displacements in source it does not mater and the rename can  be any text that's in the area so I could have included  "Invoice" if so desired. For VBA you could shell out to the task however I suggest is much easier to test and run LIVE at the cmd console. This is sufficient for your use but the drag and drop to separate has not been included as not needed by me, nor your question.

[image: https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows]

alter the window to suit your case and save file as SETNUM.bat and run at a console as using `SetNum c:\data\output\S*.pdf`

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM REM REM set "PDFsplit=C:\Apps\PDF\poppler\23.01.0\Library\bin\pdfseperate.exe"
REM REM REM if not exist %PDFsplit% echo Resource not found & exit /b 1
set "PDF2text=C:\Apps\PDF\poppler\23.01.0\Library\bin\pdftotext.exe"
if not exist %PDF2text% echo Resource not found & exit /b 1
set "workDir=C:\data\output"
if not exist "%workDir%" md "%workDir%"
if not exist "%workDir%" echo Folder not found & exit /b 2
set "Input=%~f1"
if not exist "%~dpn1.pdf" echo "%~dpn1.pdf" not found & exit /b 3

REM need to switch to files dir
cd /d "%~dp1"
echo Processing ...

REM pdfseperate is not need for this example, but would expect/allow for drag and drop as required
REM to use this file simply use the folder path of multiple files with prefix before numbers e.g.
REM getnum c:\data\output\S*.pdf

if exist "%temp%\getText.txt" del /F "%temp%\getText.txt"
for /f "usebackq delims==" %%c in (`dir /B "%~1"`) do (
echo.|set /p="%%c" "

"%PDF2text%" -nopgbrk -layout -f 1 -l 1 -x 100 -W 300 -y 50 -H 25 "%%c" -
) >>"%temp%\getText.txt"

if exist "%temp%\getText.cmd" del "%temp%\getText.cmd"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%temp%\getText.txt"') do echo Ren ^"%%a.pdf >>"%temp%\getText.cmd"

REM REM REM FOR TESTING remove REM on lines below

REM CALL "%temp%\getText.cmd"
rem del /F "%temp%\getText.txt"&&del /F "%temp%\getText.cmd"
ECHO Processing done
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a variable lets say aCntr as long and assign your value like
aCntr = 37224 and in below line use aCntr variable instead of i

```
Acro_NewPDDoc.Save 1, "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PDF\S" & i & ".pdf"
```

and before next i increment the counter like aCntr = aCntr + 1

Comment: You need to describe how to split the full PDF into smaller payslips, one per file, the payslip may not be a full page of the original PDF.

Comment: Welcome Muhammad! Read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!