# Batch file to loop open URLs, check folder for PDF download from URL, if exists move and rename files one at a time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to download PDF's fron a list of URL's in Excel and rename each with relevant information (Invoice #, Supplier Name etc).

When the invoices download, their filenames are randomgibberish.pdf and have no logical naming.

I have successfully created a basic batch file that downloads all the invoices but the issue is now renaming them. Due to size differences they don't always download in order of script so I can't use folder order to rename.

To get around this, I want to have the batch check the empty download folder for a pdf object and if it finds it, move it to a second folder and then rename to specified name. Rinse and repeat one at a time for each url.

I don't know batch so not sure how to get this done (only know VBA). Error handling for file paths isn't hugely important as it will only run in a controlled environment.

```
'open url (this part is working)'
start chrome url 
'download auto starts'

set countervariable to 0 'for breaking loop if it gets too high from multiple attempts'

loop start

 if *.pdf exists in folder A then
    *.pdf move to folder B and rename to y
    set countervariable to 0
    goto nextinvoice 'will make this counter so gotos are all unique, basically move to start new loop'
 elseif countervariable = 20 then 'counter variable to break after say 20 failed loops'
    set countervariable = 0
    goto nextinvoice
 else
    countervariable = countervariable + 1
    wait 1 second 'give download a bit more time, exits if statement and begins loop again until true'
 end if 

loop

nextinvoice
```

This is what I have so far to download the PDFs, have just set Chrome to auto download PDFs. Will update the download target folder to an empty one.

```bash
timeout 1 /nobreak
start chrome url1
timeout 1 /nobreak
start chrome url2
timeout 1 /nobreak
start chrome url3
timeout 1 /nobreak
start chrome url4
```

rinse and repeat 1000 times

Comment: I could provide you an Autoitscript for this. Should be no problem. Can I test it with a few files/urls or are the files not via internet available?

Comment: The URLs are behind a login and are confidential. Dummy links below for bike SRAM bike part manuals, these should work as stand ins?

https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/compatibility-map/road/sram-11-speed-eagle-and-flattop-chain-compatible-tools.pdf

https://www.sram.com/contentassets/86873b08dc2644a4b03aa36c6394bf85/gen.0000000005105_sm_reverb_hose_replacement_and_bleed_english_rev_c.pdf

https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/service-manuals/rockshox/front-suspension/2011-reba-technical-manual.pdf

Comment: So basically you need a loop with two lists. List A URL List B name after download. Then loop through the lists. Download file, success then rename then next. Then names are not extracable of the PDF file. You will and have to specify them by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Simply EITHER download the pdfs by true URL filename, YES I do understand you say this is NOT a true minimal example.

```
cd /d c:\downloads
curl -O https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/compatibility-map/road/sram-11-speed-eagle-and-flattop-chain-compatible-tools.pdf
curl -O https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/spare-parts/spare-parts-catalog/2022-rockshox-spare-parts-catalog.pdf
curl -O ....................../aRemote.pdf
```

or add your own name
[image]

```
cd /d c:\downloads
curl -o "Invoice 0404-Sram Eagle.pdf" https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/compatibility-map/road/sram-11-speed-eagle-and-flattop-chain-compatible-tools.pdf
curl -o "Invoice 0404-Sram Rockshox.pdf" https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/spare-parts/spare-parts-catalog/2022-rockshox-spare-parts-catalog.pdf
curl -o "whatever.pdf"  ....................../aRemote.pdf
```

OR do it the hard way see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75569606/10802527

OR avoid the whole rigmarole use the traditional vba way, You presumably have a spreadsheet list of URLs and names ?

Pseudo code

```
MsEdge.exe "https://remote1.pdf"
sendkeys ^S & "c:\users\lz02\downloads\Invoice0001-Sram Eagle.pdf" & ~,1
loop items
sendkeys ^E & url2 & ^S & filename2,1
... 
sendkeys ^E & url1000 & ^S & filename1000,1
end loop
SendKeys "%{F4}"
```

Commandline/Batchfile
[image]

[image]